# $(3+x)(2+x) = 0 \pmod 3$ Is Modular Arithmetic like any normal equation?

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let's say we have, for the integer x, this modular arithmetic equation

$ (3+x)(2+x) = 0 \pmod 3 $

Is it like any normal equation where you can say either $(3+x) = 0 \pmod 3$ or $(2+x) = 0 \pmod 3$ and then you solve it normally by saying either $x = 3k$ or $x = 3k + 1$ or nope?

I personally think I can do that because it's only logical that $xy = 3k$ then either 3 divides $x$ or 3 divides $y$ but still I want confirmation.

Comment: your approach works for prime moduli such as $3$ but not composite moduli; cf. [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#:~:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20Euclid's%20lemma,those%20integers%20a%20and%20b.)

Comment: In modulo $3$, $3 = 0$ so your equation becomes simpler.

Comment: Just to throw in technical jargon for this fact that you might see in later studies: "Since $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, $(3+x)(2+x) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ implies $3+x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ or $2+x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$."

Comment: Incidentally, the standard MathJax is e.g. `3 + x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but this is because $3$ is prime. Notice that your statement "3 divides xy implies 3 divides x or 3 divides y" isn't true if you replace 3 with, say, 4 or 6.

Comment: Ooooh. I think I get it now. It works because 3 is a prime number so there is no factor to "make it" other than 1 or 3, but if we choose as example 4 then it's impossible to say that it divides x OR y because x and y can be both 2 so 2 * 2 and 4 doesn't divide 2...Right?

Comment: @TechnoKnight Right.

Comment: So I guess the only way to solve this equation is by using the table, right?

Comment: Er, what table?

Comment: Basically, you make it into a polynomial form, in this case it's $6 + 5x + x^2$ and then you make a table that has x of 3 until (Mod 3-1), in this case it's 3 so we only take 1 and 2 and then you put these values in the equation and test until you find a value that makes the equation 0, you write that solution in form of 3k + x(The solution you found) Youtube explains it much better and clearer actually.

Comment: Well for small moduli, you can just try every value.  For larger moduli, this may be impractical.

Answer (score 1):

As J. W. Tanner says, it works when the modulus is prime.  The integers modulo a prime number, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are a field so most familiar arithmetic rules hold.  One thing to watch is that something which does not look like $0$ might be $0$  e.g. $3$ in your example.  Another is that $>$ cannot be defined in a way that retains the familiar behaviour.

It is quite different when the modulo is not prime.  E.g. in modulo $6$, $2 \times 3 = 0$ so your cancellation reduction may fail.  These are called "zero divisors".